# Doctrine 2.5 clave compuesta mapeo error

Tags: php, mysql, symfony2, doctrine2

Buenas tardes estoy realizando un proyecto en **Symfony 3** en el cual uso **Doctrine 2.5**.

En dicho proyecto tengo las siguientes tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE companies (
    id_company INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_user INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    phone INT NULL UNIQUE,
    email VARCHAR(200) NULL UNIQUE, 
    createat TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updateat DATETIME NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_company),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES users(id_user)
);

CREATE TABLE faces (
    id_face INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    image VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_face)
);

CREATE TABLE points (
    id_point INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    point_value INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_point)
);

CREATE TABLE companies_faces_points (   
    id_company INT NOT NULL,
    id_face INT NOT NULL,
    id_point INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_company,id_face,id_point),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_company) REFERENCES companies(id_company),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_face) REFERENCES faces(id_face),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_point) REFERENCES points(id_point)
);
```

Me genero el bundle con el siguiente comando en cmd:

```
php bin/console doctrine:gernerate:bundle ---namespace=BackendBundle --format=yml
```

Y me genera el bundle sin problemas. Apartir de aqui es cuando se peresenta mi problema.

Ahora creo el **mapping** con el siguiente comando:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import BackendBundle
```

Me genera el mapa de las tablas:

- companies
- points
- faces

Pero **no me genera** el mapa de la tabla:

- companies_faces_points

Por la terminal no me devuleve ningún tipo de error.

> Información buscada

He estado buscando sin ningún resultado, y lo que he encontrado es que permite el user de claves compuestas pero no se porque no me gerana el mapeo de dicha tabla.

> Tipo de solución

Busco una solución la cual me permita mantener la clave compuesta.

Si mientras usted leyó este post se le ocurrio la idea de crear un **id gérico** y dejar las otras dos campos como foregin key. **No lo considerare como una solución valida.**

> Novedades

Depués de conseguir que creara la entidad de la tabla con composite key me devuelve el siguiente erro:

```
No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "BackendBundle\Entity\CompaniesFacesPoints". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.
```

**Código de la entity:**

```
<?php

namespace BackendBundle\Entity;

/**
* CompaniesFacesPoints
*/
class CompaniesFacesPoints
{
/**
 * @var \BackendBundle\Entity\Companies
 */
private $idCompany;

/**
 * @var \BackendBundle\Entity\Faces
 */
private $idFace;

/**
 * @var \BackendBundle\Entity\Points
 */
private $idPoint;


/**
 * Set idCompany
 *
 * @param \BackendBundle\Entity\Companies $idCompany
 *
 * @return CompaniesFacesPoints
 */
public function setIdCompany(\BackendBundle\Entity\Companies $idCompany = null)
{
    $this->idCompany = $idCompany;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idCompany
 *
 * @return \BackendBundle\Entity\Companies
 */
public function getIdCompany()
{
    return $this->idCompany;
}

/**
 * Set idFace
 *
 * @param \BackendBundle\Entity\Faces $idFace
 *
 * @return CompaniesFacesPoints
 */
public function setIdFace(\BackendBundle\Entity\Faces $idFace = null)
{
    $this->idFace = $idFace;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idFace
 *
 * @return \BackendBundle\Entity\Faces
 */
public function getIdFace()
{
    return $this->idFace;
}

/**
 * Set idPoint
 *
 * @param \BackendBundle\Entity\Points $idPoint
 *
 * @return CompaniesFacesPoints
 */
public function setIdPoint(\BackendBundle\Entity\Points $idPoint = null)
{
    $this->idPoint = $idPoint;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idPoint
 *
 * @return \BackendBundle\Entity\Points
 */
public function getIdPoint()
{
    return $this->idPoint;
}
}
```

roducir el código aquí

```
Novedades sobre las novedades
```

El error **No identifier/primary key specified** viene porque al usar el generador automático no genero los id en el siguiente yml:

**CompaniesFacesPoints**

```
BackendBundle\Entity\CompaniesFacesPoints:
type: entity
table: companies_faces_points
indexes:
    id_face:
        columns:
            - id_face
    id_point:
        columns:
            - id_point
    IDX_11231BC89122A03F:
        columns:
            - id_company
id: {}  
oneToOne:
    idCompany:
        targetEntity: Companies
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            id_company:
                referencedColumnName: id_company
        orphanRemoval: false
    idFace:
        targetEntity: Faces
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            id_face:
                referencedColumnName: id_face
        orphanRemoval: false
    idPoint:
        targetEntity: Points
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            id_point:
                referencedColumnName: id_point
        orphanRemoval: false
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

¿Como he de rellenar los ids dato este caso? He intentado ponerlos copaindo el código de otro yml y cambiando las referencias pero me salta el siguiente error al hacer eso:

```
Property "idCompany" in "BackendBundle\Entity\CompaniesFacesPoints" was already declared, but it must be declared only once
```

Comment: No sé dónde puede estar el problema, pero quizás puedas mapear la tabla a mano y trabajar con ellas. Hasta donde sé, doctrine tiene soporte para claves primarias compuestas.

Comment: Puede ser que ese no sea el problema. ¿Me podría comentar, cuales son los otros motivos por los cuales no lea una tabla?.

Answer (score 0):

Como comenta @Muriano, Doctrine soporta claves compuestas:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html

Pero, por experiencia, siempre ha sido una feature un tanto experimental.

Por lo que veo, es el mismo caso que el que se presenta en la documentación:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-3-join-table-with-metadata

Yo lo que haría sería crear esas tres tablas de la documentación, ver qué código SQL me generan, y ajustar mis tablas a ese código.

Así mismo, en vez de hacer el reverse engineering, lo que puedes hacer es crear los modelos, comprobar el SQL que generarían para crear las tablas, ver que no cambian nada, NO actualizar el modelo de la base de datos, y trabajar contra la base de datos igual; debería funcionar.

Prueba y nos cuentas :)

Un saludo.

Comment: Ahora me genera la enitity de la composite key, pero me devuelve el siguiente error:No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "BackendBundle\Entity\CompaniesFacesPoints". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.

Comment: Estaría bien ver lo que estás ejecutando, y ver la salida de SQL de los comandos :)

Comment: Viendo el código de arriba:

Comment: Viendo el código de arriba:

/**
 * @var \BackendBundle\Entity\Companies
 */
private $idCompany;

/**
 * @var \BackendBundle\Entity\Faces
 */
private $idFace;

/**
 * @var \BackendBundle\Entity\Points
 */
private $idPoint;


¿No te faltan en las anotaciones el
 `@id`
?

Comment: Y esto otro??

int<?php

¿?

Comment: Si lo es porques es con el que hice pruebas y me funciono. El codigo es una simple query de todos los datos de dicha tabla

Comment: ¿A que te refieres cib qye falta un @id? Ese intity se genero automaticamente

Comment: En el ejemplo que puse: 

[http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-3-join-table-with-metadata]

Fíjate que se usa la anotación @id en los PK aunque sean compuestos; campos 

`class OrderItem
{
    /** @Id @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Order") */
    private $order;

    /** @Id @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product") */
    private $product;`

Answer (score 0):

¿Has comprobado que creas bien la clave compuesta? Prueba hacer lo siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE companies_faces_points (   
    id_company INT NOT NULL,
    id_face INT NOT NULL,
    id_point INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_company) REFERENCES companies(id_company),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_face) REFERENCES faces(id_face),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_point) REFERENCES points(id_point)
);

ALTER TABLE companies_faces_points 
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_company`, `id_face`, `id_point`),
 ADD KEY `IDX_9F267A24CCD7E912` (`id_company`),
 ADD KEY `IDX_9A267A754CEE9132` (`id_face`),
 ADD KEY `IDX_9F267A24D60322AC` (`id_point`);
```

Comment: He realizado esta prueba y no he tenido existo. Me paso lo mismo que comente arriba en la seción de novedades sobre novedades

Comment: A mi en lo personal siempre me ha gustado "no hacerle" ingenieria inversa a la base de datos. Y si ese fuera el caso, pues genero las entidades una vez y hago los ajustes en las relaciones a traves de las anotaciones, volviendo a actualizar el equema a partir de las entities